# Is the implication $f$ (improperly) Riemann integrabel then $f$ is measurable true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

The title more or less says it: Does it follow that if $f$ is Riemann integrabel, then $f$ is measurable (on arbitrary sets $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n)$? Does this theorem have a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is $f$ is Riemann integrable then it is Lebesgue integrable, so a fortiori measurable.

For *improper* Riemann integrals, the canonical counterexample is $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin t}tdt$$

However, the result still holds if $f$ is nonnegative a.e.

Comment: there are counterexamples of oscillating functions defined on the whole space aren't there? I think a good way to think about it is, that this function would be the limit of measurable step functions and therefore measurable.(but since your reasoning is different, I am probably wrong).

Comment: @Lipschitz What do you mean when you say "Riemann integrable"? Functions are Riemann integrable when they are defined over some closed bounded interval $[a,b]$, they are bounded, yadda yadda...

Comment: okay sorry, as indicated in the title I also included in my question improper riemann integrals. sorry, if this caused confusion.

Comment: well, still my question is somewhat unanswered. what would be your reasoning that (improper) Riemann integrable implies measurable?

Comment: @Lipschitz If $f$ is improperly integrable, it is the pointwise limit of Riemann integrable functions (take $f_n=f\cdot \chi_{A_n}$ for appropriate sets $A_n$). As such, $f$ is measurable.